# Why won't my nexus 7 update to Jelly Bean 4.2?

Tags: nexus-7, ota-update, 4.2-jelly-bean

I was notified that there was a system update, but when I applied it the tablet was still on the older version of Jelly Bean. I've even done a factory reset and tried again, but no luck. Are there any logs that I can look at to track down the problem?

Comment: Have you tried over WiFi, or just 3G/4G?

Comment: Can you use computer for update?

Comment: I've done this over WiFi. How do I use a computer for the update?

Comment: Have you rooted your nexus 7?

Comment: It is not rooted.  It failed pretty much straight out of the box (I bought it last week).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a hardware issue. I had two relatively pleasant conversations with tech support at google play and asus. Since it was a new purchase I just returned it.

Answer (score 1):

Before updating make full backup of your data.

For update using computer you just need to flash system partition using fastboot`fastboot flash system system.img`, where system img available at `image-nakasi-jop40c.zip` available inside `nakasi-jop40c-factory-6aabb391.tgz`, what you can download from [Google Nexus factory images page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasijop40c).

**Using scripts from tgz archive will erase your data without prompt!**

Dont't flash data, even as you got bootloop (it can be, if you has applications, incompartible with new version of firmware).