# Jellybean 4.2 update fails in middle of download for nexus 7

Tags: updates, nexus-7, crashes, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have received the jellybean 4.2 update request 2 times.  Both times I have pressed the update button and both times it has failed in the middle of the process.  No error messages.  After a few minutes, it goes back to the regular home screen.  Any idea on how I can fix this so as to update to 4.2?
Much appreciation.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/why-wont-my-nexus-7-update-to-jelly-bean-4-2 (unanswered)

Comment: Have you been rooted?

Comment: @david6 How do you know it is a duplicate? The linked question implies the download completed but was unable to apply. In the answer, it also stated they had a hardware problem. This current question doesn't give enough details to know for sure it is the same problem.

Comment: It is the same issue raised, but I was saying needs to be closed *as duplicate*. However, suggested answers for one may work for the other ..